# Laravel Botman: Can't get Facebook Messenger User

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using **Botman Studio**. I am facing an unexpected error while using **Botman $bot->getUser()** API. I have added welcome screen and get started payload. It works fine.When user clicks Get_started, i want to store user's information. But Laravel Log says:

> local.ERROR: Error sending payload: (#100) Insufficient permission to access user profile. {"exception":"[object] (BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookException(code: 0): Error sending payload: (#100) Insufficient permission to access user profile. at /..../vendor/botman/driver-facebook/src/FacebookDriver.php:501)

Please help. I am new to Botman. TIA.

## File: App\Http\Controllers\BotmanController.php

```
 public function handle()
{
    $botman = app('botman');
    $botman->hears('GET_STARTED', function (BotMan $bot) {
        $bot_user = $bot->getUser();
        Log::info(\GuzzleHttp\json_encode($bot_user));
        $bot->reply("Hello! $bot_user->getFirstName()");
    });

    $botman->listen();
}
```

I have also tried **Botman $bot->getDriver()**. But it returns null, though **Botman $bot->getDriver()->getName()** returns **Facebook**.
Laravel Version: 5.6 
Botman Version: 2.0

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have read that docs. I can get <PSID> by $botman->getMessage->getSender() then make an HTTP request to get user's information. It works fine. But still don't know what's the issue with $botman->getUser() API. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please test the same functionality using your developer account. Facebook needs to approve permissions to access user information if your bot is in production or is public (Can be accessed by everyone).
If it works with your facebook account (I am assuming you are the admin of both the facebook page and the developer app where the bot is connected.), Then you need to go to the messenger tab on the facebook developers page and scroll down to App Review for Messenger and make all the available permission requests submissions.